# Configuring MaxReceivedMesageSize for Search ServiceApplication

Tags: search, service-application, quota, settings

Browsing the SearchService application logs through the Central Administration I noticed an error occured while crawling one of my Content Sources.
There's the description:

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (3000000) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.
```

Could anyone advice me, where I can find the configuration for Search service application and increase this quota? Or some other way to do it (e. g, through Powershell)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This is a WCF exception.
Detailed explanation and how to increase the quota can be found here: http://craigrandall.net/archives/2009/04/maxreceivedmessagesize/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that it seems difficult to find where this configuration file for the Search Service application is stored, so that I can increase quota manually. Does someone have any info or documentation about it?